# Как сохранить данные в сервисе Symfony 2 в одном месте и вызвать их в другом?

Tags: php, symfony2

Вызываю сервис в слушателе Kernel.

В сервисе присваиваю некоторые данные его полям. Вызываю этот сервис потом в Twig расширении, а этих данных там нет, они null.

```
class KernelListener
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container    = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @param GetResponseEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->container->get('app.some_service')->setData('This is some data');
    }
}
```

---

```
class SomeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    /**
     * @var MyService
     */
    private $myService;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->myService = $container->get('app.some_service');
    }

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return = [
            'some_data' => $this->myService->getData() // return null ??
        ];
    }
}
```

В класс SomeeExtension при вызове getData возвращается null. Хотя по xdebug в KernelListener туда записывается "This is some data" (сначала он вызывается)

Comment: `$this->myService = $container->get('app.my_service');` vs. `$this->container->get('app.some_service')`

Comment: @Etki Название сервиса это просто пример. Изменил на одинаковый.

Comment: Если данных не много может быть использовать сессию?